# [Audio]No input or output devices found

Tags: fedora, audio, pulseaudio

I have Fedora 29 KDE. This problem started randomly. I'm not able to get any audio or sound from this OS, because of the following error: "No input or output devices found". When I try to start "pavucontrol", I'm shown "Establishing connection to PulseAudio. Please wait...".

I tried killing PulseAudio but it showed "main.c: Failed to kill daemon: No such process".

I tried "pulseaudio --start" and "start-pulseaudio-x11" and I'm shown "main.c: Daemon startup failed."

Asking this at official Fedora Forums was not helpful, so I'm asking here.

Comment: Possibly the same issue: [No sound. Pulseaudio broken ( Fedora )](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/533340)